# Remove duplicates from dict values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict of list like this

```
{'A':[1,2,3,3,2],'B':[1,2,3,3,2]}
```

Need to remove duplicates in the values only. The dict should be like

```
{'A':[1,2,3],'B':[1,2,3]}
```

Tried

```
dict((k, tuple(v)) for k, v in list_of_value.items())
```

Not helping much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the tuple to Set. As the property of set is to make it unique. The change it back to list.

```
list_of_value = {'A':[1,2,3,3,2],'B':[1,2,3,3,2]}
dict((k, list(set(v))) for k, v in list_of_value.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the same dict to save to memoy

```
dict_t = {'A':[1,2,3,3,2],'B':[1,2,3,3,2]}

for key,val in  dict_t.items():
  dict_t[key] = list(set(dict_t[key]))

#output {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'A':[1,2,3,3,2],'B':[1,2,3,3,2]}

u = {k : list(set(d[k])) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Change the d[k] to d[v]